# Failed to install untrusted sources and failed to download update information

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, software-sources

I changed my server from fastest available to main server, while trying to fix the issue with software manager (untrusted sources failing to install FYI) and I got an error.

Here's an error I get:

```
W:GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: 
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366 
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/baszczewski/qtiko/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/baszczewski/qtiko/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hakermania/format-junkie/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hakermania/format-junkie/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kroq-gar78/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kroq-gar78/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/megous/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/megous/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/faba-icon-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/faba-icon-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/moka-gtk-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/moka-gtk-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/moka-icon-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/moka-icon-theme/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/moka-gtk-theme-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/moka-gtk-theme-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/moka-icon-theme-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/moka-icon-theme-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried the steps in [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists), and I still get an untrusted sources error in software updaters.

Comment: I tried the steps in that thread and I still get an untrusted sources error in software updaters :\

Comment: according to your comment ill update my answer also, thanks for your feedback

Comment: i believe your problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first install Y-PPA manager:
  for this you have to download deb package, you cant install through PPA, since you cant update software list.

  [click on this link to download deb](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/getdeb-apps-i386/y-ppa-manager_0.0.9.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb.html)
- then open it and click on Advanced Option.

[image: Advanced Option in Y-PPA manager]

- then click on the second option( try to import all missing GPG keys) shown in image below:

[image: gpgkeys-import in Y-PPA manager]

- wait for some time. Then click on third option (try to fix all GPG BADSIG errors)
  You need to wait for some time untill its shows you notification that its done !
- in case you have upgraded your Ubuntu recently, you have to click on "Re-enable working PPAs after Ubuntu upgrade"
- then run `sudo apt-get update` After this you can go back to thing you were trying to do.

Comment: I followed your steps and when I entered y to install it just aborted. `$ sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager`
`Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y`
`Abort.`

Comment: @bobpndrgn why dont you download deb package ! after installing only then you try my method, it will work ! [click on this link to download deb](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/getdeb-apps-i386/y-ppa-manager_0.0.9.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb.html)

Comment: you can also download any missing dependency from that website

Comment: It installed through terminal today. I figured I try to run the terminal command one more time before going to the DEB approach. I imported the missing GPG keys successfully according to your steps. But it still give me the `This requires the installation of untrusted sources` error when I try to update my software through the software updater. This is what it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/5Agbvpe.png @edward Okay, wtf, it just worked. I  clicked the "try to fix all GPG erros" and "re-enable working PPA's after ubuntu upgrade" options and now it works!