# How do I configure internet connection for Terminal on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: networking, command-line, internet

I've installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and with I've Broadband connection setup, Browser connection is OK,  but Terminal not connection via internet, when command type "sudo apt-get update" by terminal then showing me Error, see screenshot, How I can fix this ?
[image]

Comment: Regarding this issue please refer the link which help you with the answer:http://askubuntu.com/questions/551655/failed-to-install-untrusted-sources-and-failed-to-download-update-information

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? I assume wget works in the terminal.

Comment: Not working this step

Comment: Proxy not setup, Because Terminal not connected via internet @bodhi.zazen